# Guice example on how to correctly wire objects

Tags: java, guice

I am trying to learn Guice and I have a question on how to correctly wire up things.  I am trying to get the call in BoofPanels doSomething() method to automatically use the MockFooImpl, but I don't think things are wired properly.

In my case I have:

```
@ImplementedBy(MockFooImpl.class)
public interface FooInterface {
    public int getBar(String one, String two);
}


@Singleton
public final class MockFooImpl implements FooInterface {
    @Inject
    public MockFooImpl() {
    }

    @Override
    public int getBar(String one, String two) {
      return 1;
    }
}


public class Baz extends JFrame  {

   private BoofPanel boofPanel;

   public Baz(String one, String two, Injector injector){
        // Constructor with args
        boofPanel = new BoofPanel("aString", 565);
        injector.injectMembers(boofPanel);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args){
       final Injector injector = Guice.createInjector();

       java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {  
           @Override
           public void run() {
               final Baz baz = new Baz("one","two", injector);
               baz.setVisible(true);
           }
       });
   }
}


public class BoofPanel extends JPanel {
    @Inject
    private FooInterface fooI;

    public BoofPanel(String aString, int anInt){

    }
    public void doSomething(){
       fooI.getBar();
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guice isn't magic. It will only inject into an object if either it creates it, or you ask it to. If you're creating your own BoofPanel, then you'll need to ask Guice to inject it. Add a constructor to Baz that looks like:

```
public Baz(Injector injector) {
    boofPanel = new BoofPanel(whatever, the, params, are);
    injector.injectMembers(boofPanel);
}
```

The BoofPanel constructor doesn't need to do anything to the fooI variable; it can leave it null. You'll also need to make main's injector variable final, so the anonymous class created in main can capture it and pass it into the Baz constructor.

If you'd rather have BoofPanel created by Guice, then you'll need to supply all the constructor parameters it needs to Guice, and call injectMembers on Baz itself.

**EDIT**: Specific changes to the code above, after edits.

1. Add a `final` to this declaration, to make it usable inside the anonymous inner class:

   `final Injector injector = Guice.createInjector();`
2. Remove this line, as it's unnecessary:

   `injector.getInstance(MockFooImpl.class);`
3. Add the injector to the invocation of the Baz constructor, to get it to where BoofPanel is created (i've also removed the unnecessary `final` here):

   `Baz baz = new Baz("one", "two", injector);`
4. Add the injector to the declaration of the Baz constructor, to receive it from the main method:

   `public Baz(String one, String two, Injector injector) {`
5. Add an injection into boofPanel to the Baz constructor, right after the `new BoofPanel` line, to get Guice to inject BoofPanel:

   `injector.injectMembers(boofPanel);`

That's it.

Comment: Unfortunately my Baz also has constructor params, so it would have to go through the same things as BoofPanel.  It seems like this could get messy and make it harder to see the original intention.  In the second case, how would one supply all the constructor parameters to Juice?

Comment: There's no problem with Baz having other constructor parameters. As long as it can get an injector (and it could even create one itself), it can inject child objects.

Comment: To make other parameters available to Guice, you would have to supply bindings for them, either with @ImplementedBy or by binding them explicitly in a module. If you have parameters of simple types like strings or collections, you will (i think) need to annotate the parameters so that Guice can tell which is which. That's a whole new question in itself, though!

Comment: This sounds like a lot of extra work and code inflation to be able to swap out one implementation in one class. I'm beginning to think that maybe Guice isn't the correct tool in this situation.

Comment: The approach i suggest involves adding one parameter and one line of code to its constructor, and a 'final' to a local variable. That isn't a lot of extra work.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not following you then.  Would you be able to provide an example of what you're referring to?  Thanks!

Comment: How about you post a more complete version of your classes - with the constructors as they are, with more parameters - and i'll show you what you need to add?

Comment: I modified the post to include the code changes you suggested.  However, it gives me a NullPointerException when I try to execute fooI.getBar();

Comment: Works for me. I've put the code as described at https://bitbucket.org/twic/boof/src/tip/src - it works perfectly.

Comment: I must have something a bit more complex in my real-world example then.  I will look into it a bit more. Thanks for your time and input!

Answer (score 1):

You probably want

```
public class BoofPanel extends JPanel {
  private FooInterface fooI;
  @Inject BoofPanel(FooInterface foo) {
     this.fooI = foo;
  }
  public void doSomething() {
    fooI.getBar();
  }
}
```

and then in your main you probably want something like `injector.createInstance(BoofPanel.class)` and it'll automatically fulfill the `FooInterface` requirement with a `MockFooImpl`.

Comment: What if I already have a constructor for BoofPanel which has other parameters and is called from Baz?  Do I just add a "FooInterface foo" in the Constructor declaration and pass in a null when called from Baz?

Comment: ...I'm not sure you can have that at the same time.  Certainly if `Baz` calls `new BoofPanel` in any way, shape, or form, Guice won't do any injection at all.

Comment: About my apparent edit to your post: i meant to edit mine, but edited the wrong one. Now fixed. One of the dangers of having edit rights, and using them before you've had any coffee. Apologies.